# Memory Access Out of Bounds - WebGL

Tags: unity-game-engine

I was getting this error when I try to load my Web game:
[image]

My game is loaded at this domain:
[Highest Flavor Website Link](https://highestflavor.com/)

This is my project settings at the time of build export:
[image]

Please give me some suggestion to solve this problem.

Comment: did you try what the popup says? open the browsers console and check the details of the error in there?

Comment: how to check the details? that I don't know :(

Comment: it should be F12, then console. there it gives the details of the error.

Comment: I was getting this kind of exception - RuntimeError: memory access out of bounds,RuntimeError: memory access out of bounds

Comment: what does you game do on startup?

Comment: this is the actual game that I was converting to web version:  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.highestflavor.humptytrumpty - at the game startup graphics, ads, leaderboard etc.. maybe loading -- I was getting splash screen then after I am getting this error.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

To run this build within the web browser - I have removed all extra things related code those can't work within the web build like in-app purchase, advertisements, leaderboard, native sharing etc...

After these things code removed from the project, I uploaded the exported build content to my hosting. Then after it started working properly.

Comment: Don't you need these parts in the final product? If so, then this doesn't really fix the issue, though it is a start in narrowing it down...

Answer (score 1):

This error happened to me due to using the `dynamic` keyword. After replacing all my `dynamic` types with `object` the error was gone. Apparently the `dynamic` keyword is not supported on WebGL builds.

Answer (score 1):

I've finally fixed the same error in my project. Here is what i did:

1. **Narrow down the line of code that crashes WebGL.**
   Go through the painfull process of pinpointing the line of code that
   is the source of the error. I had this "luck" that error occured
   when I've hit button and tried to load UIScene in Addition mode. So
   at first I found the script in the scene which when disabled got rid
   of the crash. Then I've repeated the steps and digged deeper into
   lines. After 2 hours of builds, comments etc I've found that the code
   was not working was setting the new color for UnityEngine.UI.Image.
   Which was pretty weird because in playmode everything worked ok.
2. **Find solution**. I think my solution might not be universal but I think there is something going in the Unity gameloop/lifecycle when running WebGL. The source of the problem was that i set the field that was storing my UI.Image in the Start method and then in some function I've tried to change the color.
   Property was not exposed in inspector.

   ```
   public class ModuleUI : MonoBehaviour
   {
       Image qualityBG;
       void Start()
       {
          qualityBG = GetComponent<Image>();
       }
   ...
   ```

then this line below was the cause of the crash

```
public void Set(Module module)
     {
         ...
         qualityBG.color = module.Quality.ToColor();
    }
```

3. **Fixing** - so I've added ***[SerializeField]*** attribute to the field and **set it up in editor**, dragged the Image into the inspector slot. An it fixed it. I suspect that WebGL build might perform some methods in different order, or maybe the multipleScene loaded together might to do with it. I'm not sure but the field was not set properly with previous code fot WebGL build.

Bonus:
I've also fixed some issues that was not critical (not crushing WebGL game) but not working properly as expected in playmode. This also has got to do with trying to set some object in Start() method and then doing something on them. The collection was not set up (probably null) in WebGL.

```
EffectUI[] effects;
Start()
{
    effects = GetComponentsInChildren<EffectUI>();
}
void HideAllEffects()
    {
        if (effects != null)
            for (int i = 0; i < effects.Length; ++i)
                effects[i].gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
```

And this also started working when I've added [SerializeField] to *effects* and hook it up in the scene...

Hope this will help some of you guys & gals!