# Unity WebGL RuntimeError: memory access out of bounds

Tags: flutter, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I have a Unity WebGL simple Match 3(2-D) game exported and running, and for me personally it works on like 5 different devices, but a friend of mine, who unfortunately lives too far away for me to test the devices personally always keeps running into the same error after he plays like 5-8 levels. I have all the Player Settings on default. I can not really narrow it down to a specific LOC, because I can not reproduce the error, any ideas on why that could be happening? I use Unity 2022.3.9f1. I have checked it in my browsers, it never uses more than 500MB, they have a Galaxy Tab S6 lite, which has 4GB of RAM, so it should be no problem.

[image: My Publishing settings from Unity]

And yes i have read the questions from other useres about having the same problem, but none of them helped me [Like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60655920/memory-access-out-of-bounds-webgl?rq=2) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76685555/runtimeerror-memory-access-out-of-bounds-webgl)

```
Auf flutter-crush-4ece9.web.app wird Folgendes angezeigt:
RuntimeError: memory access out of bounds
at wasm://wasm/074760d6:wasm-function[71139]:0x184eec1 
at wasm://wasm/074760d6:wasm-function[71123]:0x184c87e 
at wasm://wasm/074760d6:wasm-function[72385]:0x18e9ff1 
at wasm://wasm/074760d6:wasm-function[72382]:0x18e911b 
at wasm://wasm/074760d6:wasm-function[75998]:0x19b4c0a 
at wasm://wasm/074760d6:wasm-function[76003]:0x19b9a6a 
at Module._main (blob:https:// flutter-crush-4ece9.web.app/045de033
-15be-4559-81ac-d3aa9e1b0afe:10:323965)
at callMain (blob:https:// flutter-crush-4ece9.web.app/045de033-15be
-4559-81ac-d3aa9e1b0afe:10:403838)
at doRun (blob:https:// flutter-crush-4ece9.web.app/045de033-15be-4559
-81ac-d3aa9e1b0afe:10:404285)
at run (blob:https:// flutter-crush-4ece9.web.app/045de033-15be-4559
-81ac-d3aa9e1b0afe:10:404457)
at runCaller (blob:https:// flutter-crush-4ece9.web.app/045de033-15be
-4559-81ac-d3aa9e1b0afe:10:403497)
at wasm.//wasm/074760gb.was-function[/2385.0x82911 
at wasm://wasm/074760d6:wasm-function[72382]:0x18e911b 
at wasm://wasm/074760d6:wasm-function[75998]:0x19b4c0a 
at wasm://wasm/074760d6:wasm-function[76003]:0x19b9a6a 
at Module._main (blob:https:// flutter-crush-4ece9.web.app/045de033
-15be-4559-81ac-d3aa9e1b0afe:10:323965)
at callMain (blob:https:// flutter-crush-4ece9.web.app/045de033-15be
-4559-81ac-d3aa9e1b0afe:10:403838)
at doRun (blob:https:// flutter-crush-4ece9.web.app/045de033-15be-4559
-81ac-d3aa9e1b0afe:10:404285)
at run (blob:https:// flutter-crush-4ece9.web.app/045de033-15be-4559
-81ac-d3aa9e1b0afe:10:404457)
at runCaller (blob:https:// flutter-crush-4ece9.web.app/045de033-15be
4559-81ac-d3aa9e1b0afe:10:403497)
at Object.removeRunDependency (blob:https:// flutter-crush-4ece9.web
app/045de033-15be-4559-81ac-d3aa9e1b0afe:10:17032)
at blob:https:// flutter-crush-4ece9.web.app/045de033-15be-4559-81ac
d3aa9e1b0afe:10:1913
at doCallback (blob:https:// flutter-crush-4ece9.web.app/045de033-15be
4559-81ac-d3aa9e1b0afe:10:102753)
at done (blob:https:// flutter-crush-4ece9.web.app/045de033-15be-4559
-81ac-...
```